# Is there any module to create a set of field without creating new entity field for each one?

Tags: 7, entities

My objective is to have a module which gives me the option to create a entity field that can have multiple field values.

For example, the location module. It creates an entity field of type 'location' which can have a set of field values (country, province, city, address, etc.). In the database this module creates a table 'location' which stores all these values with a key 'lid'. The main entity field has a  'lid' value to connect with the set of values. And we are able to used tokens for all these field values.

I have tried [Field Collection](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_collection), [Multifiefld](https://www.drupal.org/project/multifield), [Composed Field](https://www.drupal.org/project/composed_field) modules, but none of those actually do this.

Answer (score 2):

If the objective is to have one entity field that stores a primary key into a custom table schema, the answer is probably no. Location (and its associated Location CCK module) achieves this by its own [widget form](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/location/tree/contrib/location_cck/location_cck.module#n427) (via [hook_field_widget_form](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21field%21field.api.php/function/hook_field_widget_form/7)) & [element type](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/location/tree/location.module#n151) (via [hook_element_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_element_info/7)). It creates various processing functions to store the data in its custom data schema. I think such a module you're describing would need to dynamically generate data schema and hook callbacks to achieve what you're wanting.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I am going to develop one. Before that I am making sure that I am not going to waste my time, if there is already one available.